# adding input values from form to json object using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

am trying to add the value of input field to json object using angularjs i wrote some codes but it doesn't work, please i need help

script section

```
 <script>
var app = angular.module("exampleApp", []);
            app.controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.loadData = function () {
                    $http.get("productData.json").then(function (response) {
                        console.log("Status: " + response.status);
                        console.log("Type: " + response.headers("content-type"));
                        console.log("Length: " + response.headers("content-length"));
                        $scope.products = response.data;
                    });

                    $scope.products = {name:'',age:'',isDead:''};
                    $scope.resurrect = function(item){
                        item.isDead = false;
                    };

                   $scope.addnew = function(){
                        $scope.products.mname = $scope.products.name;
                        $scope.products.mage = $scope.products.age;
                        $scope.products.misDead = $scope.products.isDead;
                   };
                }

            });
</script>
```

productData.json

```
[
   { "name": "Tommen Baratheon", "age": "23", "isDead": true },
   { "name": "Roose Bolton", "age": "32", "isDead": false },
   { "name": "Theon Greyjoy", "age": "27", "isDead": true},
   { "name": "Cersei Lannister", "age": "31", "isDead": false}
]
```

form section

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Charater name" class="form-     control" ng-model="products.mname">
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Charater age" class="form-control" ng-model="products.mage">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter True or false" class="form-control" ng-model="products.misDead">
<input type="submit" value="andNew" ng-submit="addnew()"></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first problem is that `$scope.products` is an array. Your markup is bound as if it's a single object though.

```
<form>
    <div ng-repeat="p in products">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Charater name" class="form-control" ng-model="p.name">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Charater age" class="form-control" ng-model="p.age">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter True or false" class="form-control" ng-model="p.isDead">
        <input type="submit" value="andNew" ng-submit="addnew()">
    </div>
</form>
```

The other problem was that you had bindings like `products.mname`, but the field is actually `name`. The next problem you have is you're initializing `products` as an `object` when you really should just initialize it as an empty array:

```
$scope.products = [];
```

The next problem you'll have is `addnew`. It needs to just push a new object on to the array:

```
$scope.addnew = function() {
  $scope.products.push({});
};
```

That will cause a new `div` to be rendered inside the `form`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i couldnt understand your last code. the one about push

Comment: @user141464, what that's doing is adding a new object to the array. This would give you a new `div` with empty values.

Comment: I changed my codes to what you recommended but unfortunately it still doesn't update the json file

Comment: @user141464, that's not going to update the JSON file. It was not clear by your question that's what you wanted.

Comment: @user141464, to be clearer, without a server of some sort (e.g. NodeJS, PHP) you're not going to be able to update that JSON file via the `$http` service.